# Multi-threaded programming : Under what situation does the variable 'iget' is equal to the variable 'iput'?

Tags: c, multithreading

**The Situation**

After reading *Unix Socket Programming*, *W.Richard Steven*, I'm writing a P2P program in which the main thread creates thread pool in which five sub-threads live. it then monitors 50 sockets with `kqueue()`. when a event occurs in a specified socket (e.g, receiving data on the socket.), the main thread copies socket descriptor into a shared array and awakes one thread in the thread pool. the sub thread then processes a request from the socket. Also, I have protected the shared array using both mutex variable and conditional variable.

**Question**

The Author presents the source codes "server/serv08.c" and "server/pthread08.c" in the Section 30.12 and 30.13 in the book, respectively, as if there is no something wrong with this code. But, when I've written a code snippet similar to one author present, thread synchronization doesn't work well.  Why does `iput` become equal to `iget` in main thread?

**Code**
--Global variable--

```
typedef struct tagThread_information
{

    int     sockfd;

} Thread_information;
Thread_information      peer_fds[MAX_THREAD];
pthread_mutex_t         peerfd_mutex;
pthread_cond_t          peerfd_cond;
pthread_mutex_t         STDOUT_mutex;
int                     iput;
int                     iget;
```

--Main thread--

```
void Wait_for_Handshake(download_session *pSession, int nMaxPeers)
{
struct kevent   ev[50], result[50];
int             kq, i, nfd;
int c = 1;

if( (kq = kqueue()) == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "fail to initialize kqueue.\n");
    exit(0);
}

for(i = 0 ; i < nMaxPeers; i++)
{
    EV_SET(&ev[i], pSession->Peers[i].sockfd, EVFILT_READ, EV_ADD, 0, 0, 0);
    printf("socket : %d\n", (int)ev[i].ident);
}

// create thread pool. initialize mutex and conditional variable.
iput = 0;
iget = 0;
pthread_mutex_init(&STDOUT_mutex, NULL);
pthread_mutex_init(&peerfd_mutex, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&peerfd_cond, NULL);

// Assume that MAX_THREAD is set to 5.
for(i = 0 ; i < MAX_THREAD; i++) 
    thread_make(i); 


while(1)    
{        
    nfd = kevent(kq, ev, nMaxPeers, result, nMaxPeers, NULL);

    if(nfd == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "fail to monitor kqueue. error : %d\n", errno);
        nMaxPeers           =   Update_peer(ev, pSession->nPeers);
        pSession->nPeers    =   nMaxPeers;
        continue;
    }

    for(i = 0 ; i < nfd; i++)
    {

        pthread_mutex_lock(&peerfd_mutex);
        peer_fds[iput].sockfd = (int)result[i].ident;
        if( ++iput == MAX_THREAD)
            iput = 0;
        if(iput == iget) // Here is my question.
        {
            exit(0);
        }

        pthread_cond_signal(&peerfd_cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&peerfd_mutex);


    }

}

}
```

--sub thread--

```
void * thread_main(void *arg)
{
    int     connfd, nbytes;
    char    buf[2048];
    for( ; ; )
    {
        /* get socket descriptor */
        pthread_mutex_lock(&peerfd_mutex);
        while( iget == iput)
            pthread_cond_wait(&peerfd_cond, &peerfd_mutex);
        connfd  =   peer_fds[iget].sockfd;
        if ( ++iget == MAX_THREAD )
            iget = 0;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&peerfd_mutex);


    /* process a request on socket descriptor. */
    nbytes  =   (int)read(connfd, buf, 2048);

    if(nbytes == 0)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&STDOUT_mutex);
        printf("\n\nthread %ld, socket : %d, nbytes : %d\n\n\n", (long int)pthread_self(), connfd, nbytes);
        printf("socket closed\n\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&STDOUT_mutex);
        close(connfd);
        continue;
    }
    else if(nbytes == -1)
    {
        close(connfd);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&STDOUT_mutex);
        printf("\n\nthread %ld, socket : %d, nbytes : %d\n\n\n", (long int)pthread_self(), connfd, nbytes);
        perror("socket error : ");
        write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, nbytes);
        printf("\n\n\n\n");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&STDOUT_mutex);

        continue;
    }

    pthread_mutex_lock(&STDOUT_mutex);
    printf("\n\nthread %ld, socket : %d, nbytes : %d\n\n\n", (long int)pthread_self(), connfd, nbytes);
    write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, nbytes);
    printf("\n\n\n\n");
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&STDOUT_mutex);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your main thread:

```
if( ++iput == MAX_THREAD)
            iput = 0;// so iput is 0 --> MAX_THREAD
```

And in your sub thread:

```
 if ( ++iget == MAX_THREAD )
            iget = 0;// So iget is 0 --> MAX_THREAD
```

Since the sub thread and the main thread runs at the "**same time**",and they are golbal values .the iput maybe equare to iget sometime.

Comment: Yes, sub threads may execute when `iget` is equal to `iput`. But when `iput` == `iget`, main thread goes to sleep, due to mutex operations, Right? But my main thread gets through `if(iget == iput)` to die. But author have never explained about getting through that if statement in the main thread. So my question is Does `iput` become equal to `iget` in the main thread?

Comment: @inherithandle When iput == iget, the sub thread goes to sleep .waiting the condition variable.Not the main thread .

Answer (score 0):

From "UNIX Network Prgramming Volume 1, 2nd Edition", chapter 27.12, page 757, from the annotations to  the lines 27-38 of `server/serv08.c`:

> We also check that the `iput` index has not caught up with the `iget` index, which indicates that our array is not big enough.

For reference the lines mentioned above ([take from here](https://github.com/nirocfz/unp/blob/master/server/serv08.c)):

```
27 for ( ; ; ) {
28   clilen = addrlen;
29   connfd = Accept(listenfd, cliaddr, &clilen);   
30   Pthread_mutex_lock(&clifd_mutex);
31   clifd[iput] = connfd;
32   if (++iput == MAXNCLI)
33     iput = 0;
34   if (iput == iget)
35     err_quit("iput = iget = %d", iput);
36   Pthread_cond_signal(&clifd_cond);
37   Pthread_mutex_unlock(&clifd_mutex);
38 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a typical circular buffer implementation.

The head and tail pointers/indices point to the same location when the circular buffer is empty. You can see this being tested in the code `while (iget == iput) ...` which means "while the queue is empty ...".

If, after an insertion at the head of a circular buffer, head points to tail, that is a problem. The buffer has overflowed. **It is a problem because now the buffer now looks empty even though it is full.**

That is to say, one unused location is reserved in the buffer; if the buffer has 4096 entries, we can only fill 4095. If we fill 4096, it then we have overflow: it looks like an empty circular buffer.

(We could use all 4096 locations if we allowed the index to go from 0 to 8192, using an extra bit to resolve the ambiguity, so that instead of wrapping to zero past 4095, the pointers would keep going to 4096 ... 8191. We would have to remember to access the array modulo 4096, of course. It's a big cost in complexity for the sake of recovering one wasted element.)

> It looks like the code bails on circular buffer overflow because it is structured such that this condition cannot happen, and so it constitutes an internal error. The circular buffer overflows when there are too many descriptors being passed from the producer to the consumer in a single bout.
>
> In general, circular buffer code cannot just bail when the buffer is full. Either the insertion operation has to balk and return an error, or it has to block for more space. So this is a special case based on assumptions particular to the example program.